# Error when verifying signed message on Etherscan

Tags: myetherwallet, etherscan, error

Why is it that my message on etherscan can not be verified correctly? I always get this message:

> I'm sorry! Signature message verification failed

[image]

Comment: How are you generating the message signature hash?

Comment: con  MYETHERWALLET

Comment: Is it possible your "address" value is incorrect? Assuming that you copied the "message signature hash" and "original message" exactly, then the only issue will be the address. Try using [this](https://shawntabrizi.com/ethsign/) to recover the signing address. (And even create a new signed message if you want!)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWZ2Oze4JrE

video tutorial to cover MEW and etherscan